# How to map / query this data with ElasticSearch?

Tags: ruby, search, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using ElasticSearch along with the tire gem to power the search
functionality of my site. I'm having trouble figuring out how to map and
query the data to get the results I need.

Relevant code is below. I will explain the desired outbut below that as
well.

```
# models/product.rb

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
  has_many :product_traits
  has_many :traits, :through => :product_traits

  mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :name, boost: 10
    indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
    indexes :categories do
      indexes :id, type: 'integer'
      indexes :name, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
    end
    indexes :product_traits, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
  end

  def self.search(params={})

    out = tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 12, load: true) do
      query do
        boolean do

          must { string params[:query], default_operator: "OR" } if params[:query].present?
          must { term 'categories.id', params[:category_id] } if params[:category_id].present?

          # if we aren't browsing a category, search results are "drill-down"
          unless params[:category_id].present?
            must { term 'categories.name', params[:categories] } if params[:categories].present?
          end
          params.select { |p| p[0,2] == 't_' }.each do |name,value|
            must { term :product_traits, "#{name[2..-1]}##{value}" }
          end

        end
      end

      # don't show the category facets if we are browsing a category
      facet("categories") { terms 'categories.name', size: 20 } unless params[:category_id].present?
      facet("traits") {
        terms :product_traits, size: 1000 #, all_terms: true
      }

      # raise to_curl
    end

    # process the trait facet results into a hash of arrays
    if out.facets['traits']
      facets = {}
      out.facets['traits']['terms'].each do |f|
        split = f['term'].partition('#')
        facets[split[0]] ||= []
        facets[split[0]] << { 'term' => split[2], 'count' => f['count'] }
      end
      out.facets['traits']['terms'] = facets
    end

    out
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    {
      id: id,
      name: name,
      description: description,
      categories: categories.all(:select => 'categories.id, categories.name, categories.keywords'),
      product_traits: product_traits.includes(:trait).collect { |t| "#{t.trait.name}##{t.value}" }
    }.to_json
  end

end
```

As you can see above, I'm doing some pre/post processing of the data
to/from elasticsearch in order to get what i want from the
'product_traits' field. This is what doesn't feel right and where my
questions originate.

I have a large catalog of products, each with a handful of 'traits' such
as *color*, *material* and *brand*. Since these traits are so varied, I
modeled the data to include a Trait model which relates to the Product
model via a ProductTrait model, which holds the value of the trait for
the given product.

**First question is**: How can i create the elasticsearch mapping to index
these traits properly? I assume that this involves a nested type but I
can't make enough sense of the docs to figure it out.

**Second question**: I want the facets to come back in groups (in the
manner that I am processing them at the end of the `search` method
above) but with counts that reflect how many matches there are *without
taking into account the currently selected value for each trait.* For
example: If the user searches for 'Glitter' and then clicks the link
corresponding to the 'Blue Color' facet, I want all the 'Color' facets
to remain visible and show counts correspinding the query results
*without* the 'Blue Color' filter. I hope that is a good explanation,
sorry if it needs more clarification.

Comment: Hiya - I'd love to help you, but I don't speak ruby and am not entirely sure what the problem is with your product traits.  Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Thanks. The most important question I have is the first one. Instead of indexing the `product_trait` field to contain an array of values like `["color#green", "material#plastic"]`, how can I create a mapping that gives me an array of objects like `[{trait: 'color', value: 'green'},{trait: 'material', value: 'plastic'}]`? Once I have this mapped correctly then I think querying it correctly won't be too hard. To clarify - I'm asking what the mapping directive might look like.

Comment: OK, understood - answer below

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you index your traits as:

```
[
    {
        trait: 'color', 
        value: 'green'
    },
    {
        trait: 'material', 
        value: 'plastic'
    }
]
```

this would be indexed internally as:

```
{
    trait: ['color', 'material' ],
    value: ['green', 'plastic' ]
}
```

which means that you could only ever query for docs which have a `trait` with value 'color' and a `value` with value `green`.  There is no relationship between the `trait` and the `value`.

You have a few choices to solve this problem.

**As single terms**

The first you are already doing, and it is a good solution, ie storing the traits as single terms like:

```
['color#green`','material#plastic']
```

**As objects**

An alternative (assuming you have a limited number of trait names) would be to store them as:

```
{
    traits: {
        color:    'green',
        material: 'plastic'
    }
}
```

Then you could run queries against `traits.color` or `traits.material`.

**As nested**

If you want to keep your array structure, then you can use the [nested type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html) eg:

```
{
   "mappings" : {
      "product" : {
         "properties" : {

            ... other fields ...

            "traits" : {
               "type" : "nested",
               "properties" : {
                  "trait" : {
                     "index" : "not_analyzed",
                     "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "value" : {
                     "index" : "not_analyzed",
                     "type" : "string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Each trait/value pair would be indexed internally as a separate (but related) document, meaning that there would be a relationship between the trait and its value. You'd need to use [nested queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query.html) or [nested filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-filter.html) to query them, eg:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/product/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : {
         "query" : {
            "text" : {
               "name" : "my query terms"
            }
         },
         "filter" : {
            "nested" : {
               "path" : "traits",
               "filter" : {
                  "and" : [
                     {
                        "term" : {
                           "trait" : "color"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term" : {
                           "value" : "green"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

**Combining facets, filtering and nested docs**

You state that, when a user filters on eg `color == green` you want to show results only where `color == green`, but you still want to show the counts for all colors.

To do that, you need to use the `filter` param to the [search API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/filter.html) rather than a filtered query. A filtered query filters out the results BEFORE calculating the facets.  The `filter` param is applied to query results AFTER calculating facets.

Here's an example where the final query results are limited to docs where `color == green` but the facets are calculated for all colors:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/product/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "text" : {
         "name" : "my query terms"
      }
   },
   "filter" : {
      "nested" : {
         "path" : "traits",
         "filter" : {
            "and" : [
               {
                  "term" : {
                     "trait" : "color"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "term" : {
                     "value" : "green"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "facets" : {
      "color" : {
         "nested" : "traits",
         "terms" : { "field" : "value" },
         "facet_filter" : {
            "term" : {
               "trait" : "color"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Comment: @DrTech i'm looking for a similar solution: Let's say that 'traits' are dynamic, the user can create different traits. How can i handle a facet for each dynamic trait?

Comment: @DustMason how can you filter for multiple traits, eg (color: 'green' ou color: 'red') and (brand: 'abc', brand: 'def') and (material: 'plastic')?

Comment: @LeonardoPinto I'm sorry its been quite a while since I've worked on this code. I don't know!